# Can I create a reblog link from a Tumblr RSS feed?

Tags: rss, tumblr

### Can I Create a reblog link programatically?

#### Is it against the [terms of service](http://www.tumblr.com/policy/en/terms_of_service)? I can't tell...

---

**Anatomy of a tumblr *reblog* link:** <sup>(unique numbers made up)</sup>

> http://www.tumblr.com/reblog/85728493821/7vu4jf89

In my RSS feed I have:

> myblog.tumblr.com/post/85728493821

So its safe to say the `85...` number is a unique **post id**

**But what is the other code?** (*`7vu4jf89`*)

The 2nd value differs for each reblog link, so its not just *my* unique identifier.

Arbitrary values do not work either.

I was thinking maybe its something Tumblr implemented specifically to prevent people from doing the sort of thing I'm attempting? Maybe its some sort of hash value combining my account identifier and the post?

Any insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Tumblr Reblogs

Ignoring the RSS part for the moment, I believe there are two official methods to achieve a working reblog link.

1. Use the template variable `{ReblogButton}` (http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes#like_and_reblog_buttons)
2. Use the Tumblr API (http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#reblogging)

In reply to your question about ***other code***. I believe this is a unique, randomly generated key, the make up of which I am not 100% sure on. The key seems be unique per post and per site.

For example, if the original reblog key is `12345678` and the post is reblogged, a new key is generated for the site that reblogged the post.

Back to the RSS part, sadly as you have probably gathered, getting the reblog key inside the RSS feed by default is impossible. My advice would be to find the permalink in the RSS feed and use an API call to return the corresponding key for a reblog.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to [construct the reblog URL manually](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/31016/24166), if you have access to the post’s HTML page:

1. search for `rk=` in the HTML source code (it's in the block opened by `<!-- BEGIN TUMBLR CODE -->`)
2. copy the value of this parameter (e.g. "1234" if you find `rk=1234`)
3. now manipulate the URL:

   1. append this value at the URL (add a slash before it, if there is none) (you can replace the slug with the value, if available)
   2. replace "post" with "reblog"
   3. remove the subdomain
4. call this crafted URL

This `rk` value (maybe "reblog key"?) doesn’t seem to be included in the feed.